# Spring MVC POST method: "The requested resource is not available" on Tomcat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring, controller

I've looked at some other solutions for this error, but none of them have worked. I have this HTML:

```
    <section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="button">
            <article id = "id-input">
                <form id = "id-form" method = "post" >
                    VOC ID:<input name = "guid" type = "text" ng-model = "input" required>
                    <button name = "button" value = "button" ng-click = "pressed()" type = "submit">Generate ></button>
                </form>
            </article>
    </section>
```

I'm trying to submit a form using the POST method when the user clicks the "button". It then executes this JS:

```
app.controller('button', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.show = false;
    $scope.pressed = function() {
        $http({
            method : "POST",
            url : "/test"
          }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
              document.getElementById("id-input").style.paddingBottom = "5px";
                $scope.show = true;
                $scope.finalinput = $scope.input;             
            }, function myError(response) {
                document.body.innerHTML = response.data;
          });
    };
});
```

After sending the POST request successfully, I have a Spring-configured class to deal with the request:

```
@Controller
public class MainTest{


    @Inject @Singleton
    private VocDBService s;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void doPost(final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        String guid = httpServletRequest.getParameter("guid");
        List<UserInfo> dataex = s.getData(guid);
        System.out.println(dataex.get(0));
    }
}
```

The problem is, after clicking the button I get message: /test and "The requested resource is not available". Why is my controller not being recognized when the POST request is sent? I'm running on a Tomcat v7 server.

Comment: Please add content type in your ajax call this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to register you controller in spring configuration or there is a problem with your dispatcher mapping in `web.xml` or `WebAppInitializer` class.

Comment: how do I register the controller in the spring configuration?

Comment: if java config `@ComponentScan("your.package")` or `<context:component-scan  base-package="your.package"/>` for xml config

Comment: Yes I have the <context> added in my xml file. Do I need to define a bean for the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Does it involve the spring-security in it. Can you once show the security configuration how you are handling it?